# Free Video maker that can animate pictures

Tags: video, video-editing, animation

I have been searching for a video maker/editor that has these requirements for as long as i can remember, do you know any free video maker for windows that can do the following:

- Able to insert images on the video then move it around EDIT: (on the canvas)
- Able to put videos on the main video (Optional)

Comment: *Move it around*? In the timeline or on the canvas? And the same goes for your second requirement. Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I already have an answer above but for those who need a little less of a learning curve *but a little more steps to the installation* there is [moviepy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy) and [Vapory](https://github.com/Zulko/vapory/blob/master/README.rst), I have to admit that I have yet to give it much of a test it looks like it can do a lot of what you are looking for.

- Free *gratis & open source*
- Cross Platform
- More specific to movie manipulations
- Can insert images into the video
- Can use a video embedded in a 3D scene e.g.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9R21SquDSk
- Can insert one, *(or more),* other videos in frames into an existing video.

An example script adding two videos together:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
# UKULELE CLIP, OBTAINED BY CUTTING AND CROPPING
# RAW FOOTAGE

ukulele = VideoFileClip("../../videos/moi_ukulele.MOV", audio=False).\
               subclip(60+33, 60+50).\
               crop(486, 180, 1196, 570)

w,h = moviesize = ukulele.size

# THE PIANO FOOTAGE IS DOWNSIZED, HAS A WHITE MARGIN, IS
# IN THE BOTTOM RIGHT CORNER 

piano = (VideoFileClip("../../videos/douceamb.mp4",audio=False).
         subclip(30,50).
         resize((w/3,h/3)).    # one third of the total screen
         margin( 6,color=(255,255,255)).  #white margin
         margin( bottom=20, right=20, opacity=0). # transparent
         set_pos(('right','bottom')) )



# A CLIP WITH A TEXT AND A BLACK SEMI-OPAQUE BACKGROUND

txt = TextClip("V. Zulkoninov - Ukulele Sonata", font='Amiri-regular',
                   color='white',fontsize=24)

txt_col = txt.on_color(size=(ukulele.w + txt.w,txt.h-10),
                  color=(0,0,0), pos=(6,'center'), col_opacity=0.6)


# THE TEXT CLIP IS ANIMATED.
# I am *NOT* explaining the formula, understands who can/want.
txt_mov = txt_col.set_pos( lambda t: (max(w/30,int(w-0.5*w*t)),
                                  max(5*h/6,int(100*t))) )



# FINAL ASSEMBLY
final = CompositeVideoClip([ukulele,txt_mov,piano])
final.subclip(0,5).write_videofile("../../ukulele.avi",fps=24,codec='libx264')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do both in [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) - it has a bit of a learning curve but:

- Insert Image into video by using the video as the texture for one object and move moving another - Yes in 3D *Demo of Video texture [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6U4KmBFeWkk)*
- You can potentially have different videos attached as textures to different faces of the same or different objects, each of which can have their own motions so you could, *potentially*, have a model of a Drive-In with a movie classic playing and fly in a new screen with a newer movie already playing on it.
- Free - Yes both gratis and open source
- Cross Platform - you can run Blender on:

  - Windows 8/7/Vista 32/64-bit
  - Mac OS/X 10.6+ 64-bit
  - Linux most recent distributions 32/64 bit
  - FreeBSD 64 bit
  - Other platforms with a bit of work

Of course you can do a lot more, video editing, 3D modelling, animation, rendering, games...